# Customize the <title> tag for all pages and posts on a WordPress website

Tags: wordpress

I have been researching a problem that I have and came across this discussion:

https://gtranslate.io/forum/how-not-translate-the-title-meta-tag-t4852.html

In there the answer provided is to use this html syntax:

```
<title class="notranslate">Example</title>
```

The issue at hand is to prevent Google Translate from translating the `<title>` tag. What I have is a WordPress website:

[www.publictalksoftware.co.uk](http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk)

I don't know how to go about changing the site to apply this syntax for all the `<title>` tags on my posts and pages. I read up about `wp_head()` but am getting lost.

Any advice appreciated.

## Update

The `header.php` for the theme I am using has this code:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>

    <?php if ( get_option('google_analitic_code') ) : ?>
        <?php echo get_option('google_analitic_code'); ?>    
        
    <?php endif; ?>
</head>
```

Comment: You want to display dynamic title as per the page or post?

Comment: The title that already is show should stay the same. I just want to insert class=“nostranslate” so that the title stays English when the user switches language. I do not know where the title tag is specified in WordPress.

Comment: Your can add title tag from current theme header.php.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Below function in function.php

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1 );
```

Add Below code in header.php befode wp_head();

```
<title class="notranslate"><?php bloginfo('name');?> | <?php wp_title();?></title>
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure this is what I need. Please see my comment on my question.

Comment: At the moment this is what is in my `header.php` at the top `<?php wp_head(); ?>`

Comment: I am trying this on the staging site and it is looking good. Thanks. Only thing I can't work out is why the result is `<title class="notranslate">Theocratic Software |Meeting Schedule Assistant 2018 | Theocratic Software</title>`. Notice `|M` instead of `| M`?

Comment: Yep, I see the subtle change. All fixed. Cool ... :)