# Setting the default pattern for Wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, page-title

On my Wordpress website the default SEO Title is:

```
%%title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%
```

The `%%sitename%%` is already part of the `%%title%%`. Under the hood:

```
<!-- AJT v16/05/18 See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50367579/2287576 -->
<title class="notranslate"><?php bloginfo('name');?> | <?php wp_title();?></title>
```

I have a lot of "posts" on the site:

[www.publictalksoftware.co.uk](http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk)

Is there a quick way for me to change their SEO Title from:

```
%%title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%
```

to

```
%%title%% %%page%%
```

Eg: Is there a "default" pattern for the Wordpress site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out. It was down to the Yoast SEO Plugin settings:

[image: Yoast SEO Title Defaults]